# google beta permissions not found terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, load-balancing, private-subnet

I'm trying to create a reserved subnet for regional load balancer. It is the first time i'm using google-beta provider and when i try to create the subnet using the following script...:

```
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "proxy-subnet" {
  provider      = google-beta
  project       = "proyecto-pegachucho"
  name          = "website-net-proxy"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.10.50.0/24"
  region        = "us-central1"
  network       = google_compute_network.HSBC_project_network.self_link
  purpose       = "INTERNAL_HTTPS_LOAD_BALANCER"
  role          = "ACTIVE"
}
```

... this error appears:

```
Error: Error creating Subnetwork: googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.subnetworks.create' permission for 'projects/proyecto-pegachucho/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/website-net-proxy'
More details:
Reason: forbidden, Message: Required 'compute.subnetworks.create' permission for 'projects/proyecto-pegachucho/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/website-net-proxy'
Reason: forbidden, Message: Required 'compute.networks.updatePolicy' permission for 'projects/proyecto-pegachucho/global/networks/hsbc-vpc-project'


  on .terraform\modules\networking\networking.tf line 18, in resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "proxy-subnet":
  18: resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "proxy-subnet" {
```

It doesn't make any sense because i have the owner role in my service account and that permissions are enabled. What could I do?

EDIT: I resolved it adding the provider directly in the modules like this:

```
provider "google-beta" {
  project     = var.project
  region      = var.region
  credentials = "./mario.json"
}

resource "google_compute_health_check" "lb-health-check-global" {
  name                = var.healthckeck_name
  check_interval_sec  = var.check_interval_sec
  timeout_sec         = var.timeout_sec
  healthy_threshold   = var.healthy_threshold
  unhealthy_threshold = var.unhealthy_threshold # 50 seconds

  tcp_health_check {
    port = var.healthckeck_port
  }
}

resource "google_compute_region_health_check" "lb-health-check-regional" {
  provider            = google-beta
  region              = var.region
  project             = var.project
  name                = "healthcheck-regional"
  check_interval_sec  = var.check_interval_sec
  timeout_sec         = var.timeout_sec
  healthy_threshold   = var.healthy_threshold
  unhealthy_threshold = var.unhealthy_threshold # 50 seconds

  tcp_health_check {
    port = var.healthckeck_port
  }
}
```

Comment: The owner role has the permission `compute.subnetworks.create`. That means the service account you think you are using is not the one Terraform is using (review ADC). Specify the service account in the HCL to ensure you are using the correct credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this using the provider lines inside of the terraform module instead the main module (also you can configure two providers):

```
provider "google-beta" {
  project     = var.project
  region      = var.region
  credentials = var.credentials
}
```